# Can closing a position trigger the wash sale rule?

Tags: united-states, taxes, options, wash-sale

I'm wondering if there is any scenario where closing a position could trigger the wash sale rules. For example, would the wash sale rule apply to the transactions in the following scenario?

In June 2016, I open 2 positions:

```
i buy 100 shares of IBM
i write 1 call option on IBM expiring January 2017
```

on December 20, 2016, I close 1 position for a loss:

```
I sell 100 shares of IBM to close my position at a loss
```

on January 5, 2017 I close my remaining position for a gain:

```
I buy to close my call before it expires
```

Notes:

the wording of the wash sale regulation says "entered into a contract or option", so I'm wondering if buying an option to close a position might qualify as "entering" 
https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/26/1.1091-1

It seems the IRS considers options and stocks to be substantially identical, as per Internal Revenue Service Ruling 85-87.

Comment: I believe you could claim that puts and calls are not "substantially identical" securities and would not be affected by the wash sale rule.

Comment: @D_Stanley  it's well established that buying a call option to open a position after selling the underlying stock at a loss triggers the wash sale rule.

Comment: @James Turner - buying a call is not substantially identical to shorting shares.  You didn't sell the stock at a loss.  You shorted shares and you bought them back to close the short share position  for a loss.  Buying a call is not substantially identically (replacement) to shorting shares.

Comment: As for the original question, all 5 positions are opening positions. They were opened simultaneously in 6/16.  The remaining 5 trades  were closing transactions.  At no point were there any  new substantially identical position opened so the 60 day wash sale window doesn't apply.  Where this gets sticky is what the strikes are and how the IRS interprets the various legs (Unqualified covered call?  Straddle violation?). Lacking specific information,  I go with D Stanley's take that there's no wash sale. And gratefully, I let my tax accounting program handle these issues.

Comment: Tax questions require a country tag. Since it was evident you are referring to the U.S., I added that.

Comment: The answer to the more general question in the title and first paragraph is a definite yes, because the wash sale window is 30 days *before* and after the sale. So if you trade XYZ, buying lot 1 on day 1 and lot 2 on day 10, selling lot 1 for a loss any day before day 41 is a wash sale and the loss is disallowed until you sell lot 1 and stay out of XYZ for at least 30 days.

Comment: Whether a call or put is "substantially identical" won't matter if buying the call or writing the put, as part of the wash sale rule is "Acquire a contract or option to buy substantially identical securities." Long calls and short puts are contracts to buy not only substantially identical securities, but actually identical securities, so they clearly can contribute to a wash sale whether the options themselves are considered substantially identical or not.

Comment: @Bob Baerker the wording of the wash sale rule says "entered into a contract or option" not "opened a position", so I'm wondering if buying a contract to close a position might be a trigger. in theory that could assign the capital loss from the December sale to the cost basis for the January purchase.

Comment: Open and enter  are one and the same.  An opening position in a long call (BTO) gives you the right to acquire the underlying (and yes, there are 3 other possibilities). Opened  has the same meaning as "entered into a contract or option."    There are 4 situations that trigger a wash sale.  The one that pertains to your question  is "Acquiring a contract or option to buy substantially identical stock or securities."   You did not acquire (BTO) such an option in January.  You STC.  Closing transactions do not trigger wash sales.

Comment: @blm - There are no lot 2's in the OP's question.  At no time did he open  anything substantially identically within 30 days of a loss.  And though not mission critical, your "day 41" is a typo.

Comment: @BobBaerker I was answering the more general question posed by the title of the post and first paragraph. It looks like the OPs trades were just an example (he says "For example"), and everyone was talking about the specific trades, so I thought I would try to answer the general question. Maybe I'm misreading the post though, and the OP really does just care about the specific trades in the post. Also, how is "day 41" a typo? If lot 2 is bought on day 10, and either lot is sold within 30 days, it triggers the wash sale rule, so that's before day 41 (or before or on day 40 if that's clearer).

Comment: @blm - OK, I see that we're both off on a tangent.  "day 41" has nothing to do with the OP's question and I mistook it as an answer to his posted trades  rather than as an unrelated example of a wash sale  violation.

Comment: i have simplified my example to highlight the issue at hand. hopefully this will not unduly narrow the focus of any answers.

Answer (score 1):

**technically no, but that's why they invented the tax straddle rules**

the **wash sale rules** don't apply because you are closing positions on both of the last two transactions. i'm not 100% certain, but it doesn't really matter because....

the **constructive sale** rules would suggest that you actually "sold" your stock when you bought the call, depending on the strike price and the date of purchase. if you bought the call and the stock on the same day, then this rule isn't an issue, but....

the **tax straddle** rules would dis-allow claiming the tax loss for the december stock sale, and instead shift the higher basis into the call position, which effectively accomplishes the same thing as the wash sale rule, except....

the **qualified covered call** rule says that the "tax straddle" rule doesn't apply if the call was purchased out-of-the-money (or close to it). the exact rules are more complicated, but that's the general idea. unfortunately....

the **qualified covered call** rules also state that the tax loss is shifted to the later tax year if you close both positions within 30 days of each other.

**so basically, yes**. any time you hold 2 opposing positions, you are subject to the tax straddle rules. while these rules are extremely vague, confusing and capriciously enforced, they will almost certainly have the same effect as the wash sale rule if not worse. moreover, because the tax straddle rules are so vague the irs might chose to apply them to surprising position combinations (e.g. buying one stock and shorting another).